# calling Stored Procedure Spring Data JPA with xml configuration

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#JPA_2.1_StoredProcedureQuery) says that it is possible to use    **named-stored-procedure-query** in xml to be invoked stored procedure via JPA 2.1.

I have tried to use 
org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:**1.11.4.RELEASE** (as resolved by
**io.spring.platform:platform-bom:Brussels-SR3**) to implement the same.

**Procedure** definition:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_DEL_LOC (p_LocationID int, p_BusinessID int, p_Status  out int)
 AS    BEGIN
  DELETE FROM  MultiLocation_XXX WHERE LocationID = p_LocationID;
  p_Status := p_BusinessID;
END;
```

**Repository interface**

```
@Repository
public interface BusinessTypesJTARespository extends JpaRepository<BusinessTypesJTA, Integer> {

 @Transactional
 @Procedure(procedureName = "PRC_DEL_LOC", name = "DEL_MultiLocation_MBA", outputParameterName = "p_Status")
int inAndOutTest(@Param("p_LocationID") 
Integer inParam1, @Param("p_BusinessID") Integer inParam2);
 }
```

**orm.xml**:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
 <named-stored-procedure-query name="DEL_MultiLocation_MBA"
    procedure-name="PRC_DEL_LOC">
    <parameter class="java.lang.Integer" mode="IN" name="p_LocationID" />
    <parameter class="java.lang.Integer" mode="IN" name="p_BusinessID" />
    <parameter class="java.lang.Integer" mode="OUT" name="p_Status" />
    <!--  <result-class>com.memorynotfound.hibernate.Book</result-class> -->
  </named-stored-procedure-query>
 </entity-mappings>
```

During debugging I found that  (See [StoredProcedureAttributeSource.createFrom(...)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StoredProcedureAttributeSource.java)), Spring code seems to be expecting the related repository method declaration to be annotated with **NamedStoredProcedureQueries** or **NamedStoredProcedureQuery**.

If not annotated by any one of them (as in my case), the supplied value of **outputParameterName** is ignored & set to "**out**" by the constructor of [StoredProcedureAttributes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StoredProcedureAttributes.java).

As a result, I am getting

```
  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [PRC_DEL_LOC]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults

  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
  PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_DEL_LOC'
  ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
  PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
```

So, is it not possible to invoke stored procedure using xml configuration only, without using **annotation** or **EntityManager**  ?

**EDIT**(Further Observation):

When I added the following into the @Entity class, things worked properly.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
 @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "DEL_MultiLocation_MBA",
        procedureName = "PRC_DEL_LOC",     //  resultClasses = Book.class,
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        name = "p_Status",
                        mode = ParameterMode.OUT,
                        type = Integer.class)
        }
     )
  })
```

Comment: http://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-jpa-named-stored-procedure-xml-annotation-example/  says: "If you prefer XML over Annotations, you can use the equivalent JPA XML mapping"

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing method to :

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "PRC_DEL_LOC")
int inAndOutTest(Integer inParam1, Integer inParam2);
```

---

I think you can directly map to the procedure in database inside JPA repository

```
  @Procedure
  returnType procedureName(InArgs...);
```

Comment: Please elaborate or share a link

Comment: @labbhattacharjee https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/jpa21/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/storedprocedures/UserRepository.java

Comment: I want to centralize all the queries (named,  native) & procedural in the orm.xml and keep the beans clean. Precisely my question was to avoid EntityManager & NamedStoredProcedureQuery!

Comment: Procedures should be kept in database, and invoked from your application code.

Comment: @fg78c, That's correct.  But I want to declare the namedprocedure in the orm.xml,   not in the entity clsss. Is that possible?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You can declare using annotation or xml, in either case it will be stored in one place - persistence unit.  But why do you want to declare ? Why not map it direct to the database?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  Please try to change method signature as in my answer above.

Comment: Have you read  my query properly? It's evident that any stored procedure must be defined in the database. But the in, out, inout parameters have to be mapped in the Spring Data JPA, which can be done by using (i)EntityManger or (ii) Annotations(NamedStoredProcedureQueries/NamedStoredProcedureQuery) or (iii)orm.xml.  I prefer the third approach.

Comment: There is no requirement to map them, `@Procedure` can abstract that. Yes, you can map in orm.xml in that case it will be stored in persistence unit, and the only way to access it is through entity manager.